# How many functions are there from 5 to 0?

Tags: functions

I have just learned that from a set of $n$ element to a set of m elements, the number of functions is $m^n$. However, how about from $5$ to $0$? $5$ is a natural number which can also be considered as a set of $5$ elements $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $0$ is the empty set.

Is the answer $0^5$ which is zero?

Extending question: how about from $0$ to $5$?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you think of any functions from $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ to the empty set? Given that $f(0)$ would have to be a member of the empty set?

Comment: Why f(0) is given to be a member of the empty set? Sorry, I really mix up all the things that I have learned so far.

Comment: If $f:\{0,1,2,3,4\}\to B$ then $f(0)\in B$. That's the definition of the function. If $B=\emptyset$, is that possible?

Comment: No...It is not possible.Thank you!!I think I got it!! Actually this is really a good place for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A:  There is no such function.   A function assigns each element in the domain to an element in the range, it's a set of ordered pairs.   Since you have nothing in the range, no such function can exist.

From 0 to 5, the answer is either 0 or 1, depending on which mathematician you ask. Some mathematicians will allow a trivial "empty function" to exist on an empty domain, some wont.

Comment: Thank you!! I will submit the answer 0 to see what kind of mathematician is my prof.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any serious mathematician would say $1$ for the second question. The definition of function is pretty clear, and you'd have to go out of your way to define function so that the empty function is not allowed. In particular, it is important that the category of sets has an "initial object."

Comment: Sorry, would you explain what is the initial object??

Comment: I've asked multiple professors at my school this very question about the empty function and gotten different thoughts,  thus my comment.  I'm pretty sure some of them are serious :)